# Magento 1.9 checkout missing contact number from Paypal Orders

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal-express

When our customers pay via paypal express checkout their contact number is not flowing through to the checkout and thus not on the Order emails, I have to go to Paypal itself to get the customers contact number?

Answer (score 0):

You can make contact number mandatory for express checkout. For the same, please login paypal.

1. Logging into your PayPal account.
2. Click on "Profile" and choose "More Options".
3. Under "My Selling Tools", click "Update" located next to "Website preferences"
4. Scroll down and you'll see the following section:

[image]

Set it as required one. So customer always need to input phone number to complete checkout. Hope this helps. If you need more info regarding the same, please check with Paypal support.